# PhantomJS, 'platform'=chrome returns 'Webkit'

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium import webdriver

path='/home/d../phantomjs/bin/phantomjs'
dcap = DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS
dcap['platform']=('Windows')
dcap['browserName'] = ('chrome')
dcap['version'] = ('15.0.87')

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=path,
                             desired_capabilities=dcap,
                             service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--ssl-protocol=TLSv1'])
url = "https://www.whatismybrowser.com/"
driver.get(url)

# The code below returns what the site sees as my browser
a = driver.find_element_by_class_name('string-major')

print("Browser type is : {}".format(a.text) )
```

https://gist.github.com/dgsbicak/4e4e450a9d78a16272563fe33d6dc5da

This is where I saw the code:
http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#desired-capabilities

Code returns:

> Browser type is : Webkit based browser on Linux

- How can I change my headers by using PhantomJS?
- Do you know better a better way to scrap by using a headless driver?
  (I want to be completely anonymous.)
- Please share your documents or sources about this topic.

note: I dont know JS or Java. Only python.

Best Regards,

Comment: See this http://tarunlalwani.com/post/selenium-change-user-agent-different-browsers/

Comment: cap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"]= "New user agent" -- Is this what I should write? This code results in TimeoutException, don't know why.

Comment: cap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = ("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/53 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.87") ## Is this what I should write? This returns: """Chrome 15 on Linux""" ## Why doesn't It return Mozilla 5 instead of Chrome 15?

Comment: The site uses different javascript objects, user-agent and few other things to determine your browser. So just changing the User-Agent won't work. One has to know what all things it checks to come to the final browser version